# Jquery Sortable/e запрет на перемещение

Tags: javascript, jquery, sortable

Как запретить перемещение более одного элемента в подключенные контейнеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как запретить перемещение более одного элемента в подключенные
>   контейнеры.

Для этого необходимо проверять количество элементов в контейнере, в который перемещаете элемент.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#main_list, ul').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connect_lists',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.attr('id') != "main_list" && $this.children('li').length > 1) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
li {
  height: 25px;
  background: #E8CC34;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #bbb;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="main_list" class="connect_lists">
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <ul id="first" class="connect_lists"></ul>
  <ul id="second" class="connect_lists"></ul>
  <ul id="third" class="connect_lists"></ul>
</div>
```